# Responsive: Resize width and height of element in ratio while resizing window

Tags: css, resize, responsive-design

I'm just trying to make my responsive div example work like here http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios

The effect should be that if you resize the window, the div will change the width AND the height depending on the ratio (in my example 41,66%).

If you view my code from the beginning in a small window, the effect will work perfectly. But if you resize the window from large to small it will not work.

Can please somebody help me to find out what's going wrong? The height will not change in ratio.

The changing div is inside a container:

```
<ul class="slide">
    <li>
        <div class="wrapper">
            Slides
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mg9ZB/

I know in Chrome it works well, but I'm using the newest version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I played around a little bit with your fiddle. At first I removed all values that influence the height of the wrapper and to center the text in the middle, I added padding of 20.83% to top and bottom.

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
ul.slide{
    list-style-type:none;
    max-width:100%;
    background:blue;    
}
    ul.slide .wrapper{
        width:1200px;
        height:0;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-color:red;
        background-image:url('img/slideshow/state1.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:1199px){
        ul.slide .wrapper{
            width:100%;
            height:0;
            border: 0;
            line-height: 0;
            padding: 20.83% 0;  /* 500px/1200px */
        }
    }
```

To see how the ratio of the wrapper changes I changed your JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var myVar = setInterval(function(){
  $('p').html($('ul.slide .wrapper').outerHeight() / $('ul.slide .wrapper').outerWidth() +' ratio');
 },1000);

});
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uTd9Q/1/) to see what I changed.

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if you resize now the ratio nearly didn't change. Found out, that I had to click "run" again in Firefox to get the right view after resizing.

Comment: Thanks Micha, that works great! There is only one thing left I don´t understand. In my real example I have a container that is wrapping the ul.slide with 450px height. The ul.slide has position:absolute; and a height of 500px (so that it´s overlapping the container). It would be great if the container with a 50px less height would also resize in ratio. But in my tests it will fail. Can you help me?

Comment: it does not work yet but the structure is already there in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/uTd9Q/2/

Comment: You should remove the fixed height and add a relative padding. Nearly the same as for the ul.slide, try the best value. As far as I know you can reach flexible height only by using vertical padding.

Comment: Hi Micha, sorry for the late reply. So I have worked out an example of the problem. I did it like you said, I made the same to the container. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uTd9Q/7/. The yellow box which will appear if you resize the window to max 1199px should overlapp the black box with 90px (540px ul.slide li wrapper - 450px container). You see that some strange happens... Don´t know how to fix it. Could you help me? I´d be very grateful to you

Comment: Hey Micha, could you help me?

Comment: Hey julesdude, sorry for the delay, but i've got no time for answering at the moment. Perhaps tomorrow, sorry.

Comment: Hey julesdude, did you solve the problem? If you add position: absolute; to a container, than make sure, that the parent-element - in your case #slideshow - is also positioned (normally relative). And add at least property top: 0; to the absolute positioned element if you want it to overlapp it's parent.
So I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uTd9Q/10/) and hope this is what you wanted.
Sorry again for the delay.

Comment: Correct, top:0; solves the problem. that´s pretty! :) Thank you very much

Comment: Did this answer work? @julesdude, please accept if it did